# Correctly implementing onMeasure() when extending a ViewGroup

Tags: android, grid-layout

One of Android samples (`FixedGridLayout`) extends a `ViewGroup` to allow for custom transitions when new items are added to a grid. The code works as expected, but doesn't implement scrolling. I thus wrapped the entire layout in a `ScrollView` expecting that this would solve the issue. However, it appears that the `FixedGridLayout` view is actually much larger than it should be, leaving a lot of scrollable space after the items.

I suspect the issue is related to the way onMeasure() is implemented. Am I right, and if so, what is wrong with this code?

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int cellWidthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mCellWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int cellHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mCellHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    int count = getChildCount();
    for (int index=0; index<count; index++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(index);
        child.measure(cellWidthSpec, cellHeightSpec);
    }

    // Use the size our parents gave us, but default to a minimum size to avoid
    // clipping transitioning children
    int minCount =  count > 3 ? count : 3;
    setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(mCellWidth * minCount, widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize(mCellHeight * minCount, heightMeasureSpec));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollView` only cares about the vertical height of the inner child view after measuring it, but it will not scroll unless the inner child sets the height to something larger than the parent.

You could call `getHeight()` on the inner view to see if it's computed a larger value than you expected. The method is only valid after layout is complete.

The code you posted does appear to have a mistake in it.

```
int minCount =  count > 3 ? count : 3;
setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(mCellWidth * minCount, widthMeasureSpec),
        resolveSize(mCellHeight * minCount, heightMeasureSpec));
```

The code is setting the `width` and `height` based upon the **total** number of children. If I assume a grid layout pattern, then the width is calculated as `mCellWidth * columns` and height is calculated as `mCellHeight * rows`.

If you set the height value using the total number of children, then this would explain why your scrolling beyond the bottom of the layout.